# fiware-orion notification failure with https

Tags: fiware-orion

I have a problem with my Fiware-Orion (2.1.0) notifications with Quantum-Leap for managing time-series datas (related to that component [quantumleap](https://github.com/smartsdk/ngsi-timeseries-api) ).

Both are within Docker containers and using HTTPS.

In orion I create the subscription for Quantum-Leap. **It works**.

And when I create or update an entity, Orion send me an 200 OK response and the notification never reach Quantum-Leap.

I have nothing in logs.

When I make a request directly to an endpoint using Curl or Postman, the request **works**. Requests using Orion always fail.

Here is the curl used by Postman to QuantmLeap that works.

```
  curl -X POST \
  https://ql1-dev.mydomain.com/v2/notify \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Fiware-Service: svctestnca' \
  -H 'Fiware-ServicePath: /svcpath/testnca' \
  -H 'Host: ql1-dev.intranice.ville-nice.fr' \
  -H 'Ngsiv2-AttrsFormat: normalized' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 76255023-47e3-44c5-8abf-d184a1dd77f0,adaa68e0-abf4-4fea-855d-39c3469ba1d4' \
  -H 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.11.0' \
  -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-length: 279' \
  -d '{
  "subscriptionId": "5c62b47f132e5369012c4726",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "Testnca:testnca1",
      "type": "Testnca",
      "dateObserved": {
        "type": "DateTime",
        "value": "2019-02-04T16:19:22.00Z"
      },
      "mesure": {
        "type": "Number",
        "value": 2.0
        }
    }
  ]
}'
```

Thanks for help and advices

Comment: Could you upgrade to Orion 2.2.0 and test again, please? Orion 2.2.0 include some extra funtionality to debug this kind of scenarios (see https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/2.2.0/admin/diagnosis/index.html#diagnose-notification-reception-problems)

Comment: Hi, i upgraded to Orion 2.2.0 and when I make my requests, I have that line from Orion logs: `time=Monday 29 Apr 11:49:26 2019.364Z | lvl=WARN | corr=d66c539a-6a74-11e9-991b-0242ac120009 | trans=1556536262-499-00000000005 | from=10.6.11.36 | srv=svctestnca | subsrv=/svcpath/testnca | comp=Orion | op=httpRequestSend.cpp[625]:httpRequestSendWithCurl | msg=Notification response NOT OK, http code: 503`

Comment: When I make a request directly to an endpoint using Curl or Postman, the request **works**. Requests using Orion always fail

Comment: In order to have the full information, could you edit your question post and add the curl command you are using that works, please?

Answer (score 2):

I tried to use HAProxy like in this [Stack-Overfow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55868359/https-notification-doesnt-reach-cygnus) and it solves my problem.

Orion always add the port number to my request and I missed that element.

Thank you all and especially [StephaneRouxNCA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11415638/stephanerouxnca)