# HTTPS notification doesn't reach cygnus

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

Orion version is `2.1.0`
Orion is started in HTTPS using the `-https` option

We use the "HTTPS" protocol schema in URL in our subscriptions --> reference" : "https://cygnus.domain.com/notify"

When we insert an Entity matching the subscription, the Entity is created in Orion, but not in STH.

However Orion Logs return: Notification Successfully Sent to https://cygnus.domain.com:443/notify

If we use the "HTTP" protocol schema in URL in our subscriptions it works
If we use curl to notify dirctly Cygnus in HTTP or HTTPS it works

Orion Logs bellow:

```
time=Friday 22 Feb 11:24:28 2019.158Z | lvl=INFO | corr=N/A | trans=1550831768-689-00000000058 | from=pending | srv=pending | subsrv=pending | comp=Orion | op=logMsg.h[1832]:lmTransactionStart | msg=Starting transaction to https://cygnus.domain.com:443/notify
 time=Friday 22 Feb 11:24:28 2019.159Z | lvl=INFO | corr=6a8319ac-3694-11e9-872e-0242c0a81006 | trans=1550831768-689-00000000056 | from=10.6.11.36 | srv=svctestnca | subsrv=/svcpath/testnca | comp=Orion | op=logMsg.h[1916]:lmTransactionEnd | msg=Transaction ended
 time=Friday 22 Feb 11:24:28 2019.177Z | lvl=INFO | corr=N/A | trans=1550831768-689-00000000057 | from=pending | srv=pending | subsrv=pending | comp=Orion | op=httpRequestSend.cpp[615]:httpRequestSendWithCurl | msg=Notification Successfully Sent to https://cygnus.domain.com:443/notify
 time=Friday 22 Feb 11:24:28 2019.159Z | lvl=INFO | corr=N/A | trans=1550831768-689-00000000058 | from=pending | srv=pending | subsrv=pending | comp=Orion | op=httpRequestSend.cpp[594]:httpRequestSendWithCurl | msg=Sending message 20 to HTTP server: sending message of 826 bytes to HTTP server
 time=Friday 22 Feb 11:24:28 2019.176Z | lvl=INFO | corr=N/A | trans=1550831768-689-00000000058 | from=pending | srv=pending | subsrv=pending | comp=Orion | op=logMsg.h[1916]:lmTransactionEnd | msg=Transaction ended
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you upgrade to Orion 2.2.0 and test again, please? Orion 2.2.0 include some extra funtionality to debug this kind of scenarios (see https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/2.2.0/admin/diagnosis/index.html#diagnose-notification-reception-problems)

Comment: I've upgraded to Orion 2.2.0 Orion logs  bellow :
 
time=Tuesday 30 Apr 11:52:21 2019.341Z | lvl=WARN | corr=697a13ce-6b3e-11e9-8041-0242ac140006 | trans=1556612725-897-00000000035 | from=172.16.207.135 | srv=svctestnca | subsrv=/svcpath/testnca | comp=Orion | op=httpRequestSend.cpp[625]:httpRequestSendWithCurl | msg=Notification response NOT OK, http code: 503

Answer (score 1):

**This problem has been solved**
The subscription reference is https://cygnus.domain.com/notify
but Orion transform this in https://cygnus.domain.com:443/notify

We have a HAProxy to load balance requests. An ACL is present to accept the doamin cygnus.domain.com but no ACL is present to accept cygnus.domain.com:443

Modifying the ACL resolve the problem

- Old ACL : acl IS_Cygnus         hdr(host) -i cygnus.domain.com
- New ACL : acl IS_Cygnus         hdr_beg(host) -i cygnus.domain.com

Comment: Makes sense. Note that default port for HTTPS protocol is 443. Orion is honouring this default. Happy to know you solved! :)